# Mean over subpopulations - output to LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, stata

My data looks like the following:

```
var1 dummy1 dummy2
.9  1   0
.4  1   0
.6  0   1
.3  0   1
.2  0   0
.1  0   0
```

I have a variable of interest, `var1` that I would like to summarize over three sub-populations, defined by two dummy variables: `dummy1` and `dummy2`.

I can easily do this in Stata using the `mean` command:

```
. mean var1, over(dummy1 dummy2)

--------------------------------------------------------------
        Over |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
var1         |
   _subpop_1 |        .15        .05      .0214709    .2785291
   _subpop_2 |        .45        .15      .0644127    .8355873
   _subpop_3 |        .65        .25      .0073545    1.292645
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I have Stata generate LaTeX code for such a table?

I have tried using `esttab` for that, but it seems that it does not support the right format.

Alternatively, is there a simple way to get this done in R?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have installed the *community-contributed* command `matselrc` (`findit matselrc`):

```
clear

input var1 dummy1 dummy2
.9  1   0
.4  1   0
.6  0   1
.3  0   1
.2  0   0
.1  0   0
end

. mean var1, over(dummy1 dummy2)

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =          6

         Over: dummy1 dummy2
    _subpop_1: 0 0
    _subpop_2: 0 1
    _subpop_3: 1 0

--------------------------------------------------------------
        Over |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
var1         |
   _subpop_1 |        .15        .05      .0214709    .2785291
   _subpop_2 |        .45        .15      .0644127    .8355873
   _subpop_3 |        .65        .25      .0073546    1.292645
--------------------------------------------------------------

. matrix A = r(table) 
. matrix A = A'

. matselrc A B, c(1 2 5 6)
. matrix colnames B = "Mean"  "Std. Err."  "[95% Conf." "Interval]"
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
. esttab matrix(B), nomtitles

----------------------------------------------------------------
                     Mean    Std. Err.   [95% Conf.    Interval]
----------------------------------------------------------------
var1                                                            
_subpop_1             .15          .05     .0214709     .2785291
_subpop_2             .45          .15     .0644127     .8355873
_subpop_3             .65          .25     .0073546     1.292645
----------------------------------------------------------------
```